# Python pandas left join result in empty values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I attempt to left join these two dataframe by using this `landline.merge(AreaCode, how = 'left', left_on = 'source', right_on = 'codes')`
However the values become ALL null, what did I do wrongly?

**edited 1**
I have used following code to make sure the data type are the same.

```
landline['source'] = landline['source'].astype(str)
AreaCode['codes'] = AreaCode['codes'].astype(str)
```

- Failed merge

```
    datetime              source       Day         code     area
0   2019-01-01 16:22:46 |        |  Tuesday    |    NaN   |  NaN
1   2019-01-02 09:33:29 |        |  Wednesday  |    NaN   |  NaN
2   2019-01-02 09:44:46 |        |  Wednesday  |    NaN   |  NaN
```

- landline dataframe

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3562 entries, 0 to 7097
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   datetime  3555 non-null   object
 1   source    3562 non-null   object
 2   Day       3555 non-null   object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 111.3+ KB
```

- areacode dataframe

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 611 entries, 0 to 610
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   codes   611 non-null    object
 1   area    611 non-null    object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 9.7+ KB
```

Comment: Probably because all values in 'source' column is `landline` an empty string, while it's not true for 'codes' in `areacode`. So, there wasn't a match at all.

Comment: make sure that the data type of `source` and `codes` columns are the same

Comment: However, I have also tried to covert 'source' and 'codes' into `str` data type, the combined result still empty.

Comment: @Jason , They look like the same in 'Object'. Anything I could do in order to make them in consistent data type?

Comment: using `.astype(str)`?

Comment: `landline['source'] = landline['source'].astype(str)
AreaCode['codes'] = AreaCode['codes'].astype(str)`
This is not working, and I get so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your command/code.

It might be all values in 'source' column are really not matching with codes.

If you think that values are present, but still are not matching, probably the values of source column are different type. In Pandas, 'Object' type doesn't mean it is a string, it means it is mixed type.

For example:

```
df_l = pd.DataFrame({'source': [1,'1','2','2']})
df_r = pd.DataFrame({'codes':['1','2'], 'value':['x','y']})

df_l.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   source  4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes

df_r.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   codes   2 non-null      object
 1   value   2 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes

df_l.merge(df_r, how='left', left_on=['source'], right_on=['codes'])
  source codes value
0      1   NaN   NaN
1      1     1     x
2      2     2     y
3      2     2     y
```

In the above example df_l, has both int & string of '1' but info shows as object.
If you see the merge result, it matches with one row which is string and doesn't match with another row which is int.

Comment: If it is possible that because some values of left table can't match with right table, which causes this error.
Could I convert object into string data type?

Comment: Yes, it can help, If value of both is same. But if value of source can not be found in codes, obviously it will return Nan. But I just observed your edit1 where you converted it to 'str' type. Is problem persists even after converting ?

Comment: I have rerun the whole coding again and examine the values of `source`, I found that the values are empty there. I think that's why even though I change the data type and it doesn't work.

Much appreciated for your help!